# Automating a IE browser launched using Citrix

Tags: automation, citrix

I need to Automate a Client Site launched using Citrix application. I cannot able to select the window.

My Question: is it possible to automate the application launched in Citrix?

Comment: You haven't provided much detail. It would be useful to give specific information about what you want to do when you say "automate".

Comment: Its about launching a site.say for example am going about launching facebook by providing username and password if connecting a facebook via citrix i cannot able to identify the browser window in watin automation

Comment: this can be done by selenium webdriver

Comment: I tried even with selenium webdriver Aura but the driver cannot able to find the respective window launched using citrix

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the type of automation you're trying to do from the client. The browser running on the server is presented on the client machine as an image. If you want to do this kind of automation, you have to run the automation logic on the server where the browser is actually running.

So you could write your own custom app that (a) does a command line launch of the browser; (b) automates the browser to do whatever you want. You then get the Citrix admin to publish your app, which your users then run instead.